# How do I change the names shown on boot menu?

Tags: operating-system, rename, boot, bios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra9jl.jpg)

I have two ssd's (Samsung and EVM) with windows 11 on my Acer predator PH315-54 laptop. They show as "Windows Boot Manager" on my Boot Menu in BIOS.When I try to rearrange the priority order for loading I can't tell them apart ultil the OS loads. Is there a way I can rename them?

I tried "bcdedit" on my cmd and tried "bcdedit /set "{current}" description "Windows 11 SAMSUNG" It changed under windows boot loader section but not under Windows boot Manager. The above code will be helpful if my device shows two bootable devices.

**My Laptop doesn't show two bootable devices. I always change the priority for switching between them.
I want to change the name which is displayed on the bios boot menu.**

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot change the name on BIOS but you can check your disk's names by executing the 'diskpart' command before entering bios with the cmd. Or you can check and change it from disk management from your windows computer